# Find all rows from a table which don't have references in any other tables from the same database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm using foreign keys and InnoDB.
I have an image table which contains all uploaded images data.
Every time i delete a connection to the image table, i usually mark the specific row from image table as deleted. So the garbage collector usually deletes unused images.

There isn't any image used by more than 1 connection at a time.

For optimizations purposes i want to find all rows which remained without connections in image  table(column "Id"). Because any unused row is a zombie row.

From our failed tests there remained some rows without connections.

example image table:

```
CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FileName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Is_Deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Disabled` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=816 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all your "zombie" rows with something like this query :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  image
WHERE
  image.`Id` NOT IN (SELECT table1.IdFK FROM table1 UNION 
                     SELECT table2.IdFK FROM table2 UNION
                     SELECT table3.IdFK FROM table3 ... )
```

Basically it checks if the image.Id is present as a FK in another table.  You can add as many `UNION` that you need.

As a side note maybe should consider adding integrity constraints?

Comment: I would wanted to avoid this situation but now i know that there isn't a reliable solution for it. The problem is that image tables needs to communicate with the storage engine(php) for phisical deletion first which is impossible. The problem is that there are hundreds of tables which integrates image table... And the column name is very diverse. Actually this is a problem of FKs... So i need to do everything manually

Comment: I only wanted to make a general cleanup. Maybe i can find a dirty way to do it, like finding all the tables and columns which have FKs in image table and then to generate the union query and then mark all to let image garbage collector service to do its job.